# Get Current month and year from FSCalender -Swift

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

I am using FSCalender for ma project. I need to scroll the calender for getting next month.

I am using this code to get the change notification

```
 func calendarCurrentMonthDidChange(_ calendar: FSCalendar!) {
    print("Changed")

    print("ss",ss)
    // Do something
}
```

what I need is to get the current month and year form the calendar object..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `calendar.currentPage` to get the `Date` value. `Then use Component`

```
let currentPageDate = calendar.currentPage

let month = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: currentPageDate)

print(month)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as mentioned in https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar/issues/508

```
    let values = Calendar.current.dateComponents([Calendar.Component.month, Calendar.Component.year], from: self.calendar.currentPage)
CURRENT_YEAR = values.year
CURRENT_MONTH = values.month

let range = Calendar.current.range(of: Calendar.Component.day, in: Calendar.Component.month, for: self.calendar.currentPage)
TOTAL_DAYS = range.count
```